# Manage a lock in a file system

Tags: java, locking

I have two Java processes and need to make sure that they do not simultaneously access directory `/dir`. I am not sure how to properly implement this behaviour.

My idea would be to define a certain file `lock.txt` and do something like

```
if not (lock.txt exists)
   { 
    create lock.txt with content "process 1"
    do something in /dir
    delete lock.txt
   }
```

But I guess I could run into some kind of race condition if both processes check this simultaneously.

EDIT: my Java processes are separate programs.

Comment: define a access_flag that you can check everytime you want to access the folder...

Comment: if multi threading then carefully use a volatile one...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...- should prevent races.

Comment: And what happens if the process which created the lock file crashes before it deletes it?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the FileLock class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html

You could have found this with a bit of googling

Comment: It says: "Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore unspecified."

Comment: This is there best you going to get with Java file locks. I would expect this to work on Linux and OSX but maybe not Windows. If that is not good enough you should open a TCP channel between the processes and resolve contention over that